# Plug-and-play usb-midi controller. How?

Tags: microcontroller, usb, avr, midi

I am wondering how plug-and-play usb-midi controllers are created?

To the moment I've created a simple midi controller based on Arduino Uno, but I am not able to use it directly. I have to use something like Serial->Midi convertor (Hairless Midi)

Now my aim is to create a midi controller from scratch.
I've chosen an AVR micro controller as a brain for the device. But I can not find any info, how to create a device which can be connected to a computer without additional setting.

So, can anyone explain how to create a plug-and-play midi device?

Comment: See also [Implementing a class-compliant USB MIDI device](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/87601/implementing-a-class-compliant-usb-midi-device).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a [USB-MIDI](http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs/midi10.pdf) endpoint.

The Uno, with its secondary USB-capable MCU being used for serial communications by default, is not the best choice for this. Consider using a device with native USB support such as the Leonardo (ATmega32U4) instead.